# How to set route with dynamic link

Tags: flutter

I have a link: `/Detail/{id}`
with: `/Detail` => route to screen widget `Detail`
and: `id` is dynamic.

How can I define dynamic router in order to when click to the link, it will navigate to screen widget `Detail`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Use `onGenerateRoute` for generating route according to your logic

```
MaterialApp(
  // Define initial route
  initialRoute: '/',
  onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
  // Define your logic according to data
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage());
      case '/detail':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => DetailsPage(
            data: settings.arguments,
          ),
        );
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UnknownPage());
    }
  },
);
```